# ActiveMQ 5.14.1 conflicts with htmlunit and jquery

Tags: jquery, activemq-classic, htmlunit

I recently upgraded ActiveMQ to 5.14.1 from 5.11.1. My application having some UI tests written with the help of htmlunit and the tests were running fine before the up-gradation. Once after upgrading the ActiveMQ, i am seeing full of warnings while i am running my tests. some of the warnings are listed below. I do not understand how activeMQ related jars involved in these king of warnings. I am using htmlunit 2.18.

```
        WARN | CSS error: 'https://localhost:8888/smi/style/bootstrap.css' [3570:17] Error in expression; ':' found after identifier "progid".
 []  WRN | CSS error: 'https://loclhost:8888/portl/style/bootstrp.css' [6313:17] Error in expression; ':' found fter identifier "progid".
 []  WRN | CSS error: 'https://loclhost:8888/portl/style/bootstrp.css' [6322:17] Error in expression; ':' found fter identifier "progid".
 [] ERROR | runtimeError: messge=[n inlid or illegl selector ws specified (selector: '*,:x' error: Inlid selector: *:x).] sourceNme=[https://loclhost:8888/portl/s/query-1.11.1.min.s] line=[2] lineSource=[null] lineOffset=[0]

  WRN | CSS error: 'https://loclhost:8888/portl/style/bootstrp.min.css;sessionid=pnku9gus7m411kwt5c5nyklwb' [10:49310] Error in expression; ':' found fter identifier "progid".
 []  WRN | CSS error: 'https://loclhost:8888/portl/style/bootstrp.min.css;sessionid=pnku9gus7m411kwt5c5nyklwb' [10:102069] Error in expression; ':' found fter identifier "progid".
 []  WRN | CSS error: 'https://loclhost:8888/portl/style/bootstrp.min.css;sessionid=pnku9gus7m411kwt5c5nyklwb' [10:102520] Error in expression; ':' found fter identifier "progid".
 []  WRN | CSS error: 'https://loclhost:8888/portl/style/bootstrp-theme.min.css;sessionid=pnku9gus7m411kwt5c5nyklwb' [10:874] Error in expression; ':' found fter identifier "progid".
 []  WRN | CSS error: 'https://loclhost:8888/portl/style/bootstrp-theme.min.css;sessionid=pnku9gus7m411kwt5c5nyklwb' [10:992] Error in expression; ':' found fter identifier "progid".
 []  WRN | CSS error: 'https://loclhost:8888/portl/style/bootstrp-theme.min.css;sessionid=pnku9gus7m411kwt5c5nyklwb' [10:1638] Error in expression; ':' found fter identifier "progid".
 []  WRN | CSS error: 'https://loclhost:8888/portl/style/bootstrp-theme.min.css;sessionid=pnku9gus7m411kwt5c5nyklwb' [10:1756] Error in expression; ':' found fter identifier "progid".
 []  WRN | CSS error: 'https://loclhost:8888/portl/style/bootstrp-theme.min.css;sessionid=pnku9gus7m411kwt5c5nyklwb' [10:2359] Error in expression; ':' found fter identifier "progid".
 []  WRN | CSS error: 'https://loclhost:8888/portl/style/bootstrp-theme.min.css;sessionid=pnku9gus7m411kwt5c5nyklwb' [10:2477] Error in expression; ':' found fter identifier "progid".
 []  WRN | CSS error: 'https://loclhost:8888/portl/style/bootstrp-theme.min.css;sessionid=pnku9gus7m411kwt5c5nyklwb' [10:3077] Error in expression; ':' found fter identifier "progid".
 []  WRN | CSS error: 'https://loclhost:8888/portl/style/bootstrp-theme.min.css;sessionid=pnku9gus7m411kwt5c5nyklwb' [10:3195] Error in expression; ':' found fter identifier "progid".
 []  WRN | CSS error: 'https://loclhost:8888/portl/style/bootstrp-theme.min.css;sessionid=pnku9gus7m411kwt5c5nyklwb' [10:3780] Error in expression; ':' found fter identifier "progid".
 []  WRN | CSS error: 'https://loclhost:8888/portl/style/bootstrp-theme.min.css;sessionid=pnku9gus7m411kwt5c5nyklwb' [10:3898] Error in expression; ':' found fter identifier "progid".
 []  WRN | CSS error: 'https://loclhost:8888/portl/style/bootstrp-theme.min.css;sessionid=pnku9gus7m411kwt5c5nyklwb' [10:4500] Error in expression; ':' found fter identifier "progid".
 []  WRN | CSS error: 'https://loclhost:8888/portl/style/bootstrp-theme.min.css;sessionid=pnku9gus7m411kwt5c5nyklwb' [10:4618] Error in expression; ':' found fter identifier "progid".
 []  WRN | CSS error: 'https://loclhost:8888/portl/style/bootstrp-theme.min.css;sessionid=pnku9gus7m411kwt5c5nyklwb' [10:5393] Error in expression; ':' found fter identifier "progid".
 []  WRN | CSS error: 'https://loclhost:8888/portl/style/bootstrp-theme.min.css;sessionid=pnku9gus7m411kwt5c5nyklwb' [10:5856] Error in expression; ':' found fter identifier "progid".
 []  WRN | CSS error: 'https://loclhost:8888/portl/style/bootstrp-theme.min.css;sessionid=pnku9gus7m411kwt5c5nyklwb' [10:6239] Error in expression; ':' found fter identifier "progid".
 []  WRN | CSS error: 'https://loclhost:8888/portl/style/bootstrp-theme.min.css;sessionid=pnku9gus7m411kwt5c5nyklwb' [10:6357] Error in expression; ':' found fter identifier "progid".
 []  WRN | CSS error: 'https://loclhost:8888/portl/style/bootstrp-theme.min.css;sessionid=pnku9gus7m411kwt5c5nyklwb' [10:6873] Error in expression; ':' found fter identifier "progid".
 []  WRN | CSS error: 'https://loclhost:8888/portl/style/bootstrp-theme.min.css;sessionid=pnku9gus7m411kwt5c5nyklwb' [10:7403] Error in expression; ':' found fter identifier "progid".
 []  WRN | CSS error: 'https://loclhost:8888/portl/style/bootstrp-theme.min.css;sessionid=pnku9gus7m411kwt5c5nyklwb' [10:7521] Error in expression; ':' found fter identifier "progid".
 []  WRN | CSS error: 'https://loclhost:8888/portl/style/bootstrp-theme.min.css;sessionid=pnku9gus7m411kwt5c5nyklwb' [10:7850] Error in expression; ':' found fter identifier "progid".
 []  WRN | CSS error: 'https://loclhost:8888/portl/style/bootstrp-theme.min.css;sessionid=pnku9gus7m411kwt5c5nyklwb' [10:8694] Error in expression; ':' found fter identifier "progid".
 []  WRN | CSS error: 'https://loclhost:8888/portl/style/bootstrp-theme.min.css;sessionid=pnku9gus7m411kwt5c5nyklwb' [10:9078] Error in expression; ':' found fter identifier "progid".
 []  WRN | CSS error: 'https://loclhost:8888/portl/style/bootstrp-theme.min.css;sessionid=pnku9gus7m411kwt5c5nyklwb' [10:9465] Error in expression; ':' found fter identifier "progid".
 []  WRN | CSS error: 'https://loclhost:8888/portl/style/bootstrp-theme.min.css;sessionid=pnku9gus7m411kwt5c5nyklwb' [10:9851] Error in expression; ':' found fter identifier "progid".
 []  WRN | CSS error: 'https://loclhost:8888/portl/style/bootstrp-theme.min.css;sessionid=pnku9gus7m411kwt5c5nyklwb' [10:10233] Error in expression; ':' found fter identifier "progid".
 []  WRN | CSS error: 'https://loclhost:8888/portl/style/bootstrp-theme.min.css;sessionid=pnku9gus7m411kwt5c5nyklwb' [10:10598] Error in expression; ':' found fter identifier "progid".
 []  WRN | CSS error: 'https://loclhost:8888/portl/style/bootstrp-theme.min.css;sessionid=pnku9gus7m411kwt5c5nyklwb' [10:10971] Error in expression; ':' found fter identifier "progid".
 []  WRN | CSS error: 'https://loclhost:8888/portl/style/bootstrp-theme.min.css;sessionid=pnku9gus7m411kwt5c5nyklwb' [10:11341] Error in expression; ':' found fter identifier "progid".
 []  WRN | CSS error: 'https://loclhost:8888/portl/style/bootstrp-theme.min.css;sessionid=pnku9gus7m411kwt5c5nyklwb' [10:11714] Error in expression; ':' found fter identifier "progid".
 []  WRN | CSS error: 'https://loclhost:8888/portl/style/bootstrp-theme.min.css;sessionid=pnku9gus7m411kwt5c5nyklwb' [10:12086] Error in expression; ':' found fter identifier "progid".
 []  WRN | CSS error: 'https://loclhost:8888/portl/style/bootstrp-theme.min.css;sessionid=pnku9gus7m411kwt5c5nyklwb' [10:13263] Error in expression; ':' found fter identifier "progid".
 []  WRN | CSS error: 'https://loclhost:8888/portl/style/bootstrp-theme.min.css;sessionid=pnku9gus7m411kwt5c5nyklwb' [10:13756] Error in expression; ':' found fter identifier "progid".
 []  WRN | CSS error: 'https://loclhost:8888/portl/style/bootstrp-theme.min.css;sessionid=pnku9gus7m411kwt5c5nyklwb' [10:14137] Error in expression; ':' found fter identifier "progid".
 []  WRN | CSS error: 'https://loclhost:8888/portl/style/bootstrp-theme.min.css;sessionid=pnku9gus7m411kwt5c5nyklwb' [10:14518] Error in expression; ':' found fter identifier "progid".
 []  WRN | CSS error: 'https://loclhost:8888/portl/style/bootstrp-theme.min.css;sessionid=pnku9gus7m411kwt5c5nyklwb' [10:14896] Error in expression; ':' found fter identifier "progid".
 []  WRN | CSS error: 'https://loclhost:8888/portl/style/bootstrp-theme.min.css;sessionid=pnku9gus7m411kwt5c5nyklwb' [10:15277] Error in expression; ':' found fter identifier "progid".
 []  WRN | CSS error: 'https://loclhost:8888/portl/style/bootstrp-theme.min.css;sessionid=pnku9gus7m411kwt5c5nyklwb' [10:15657] Error in expression; ':' found fter identifier "progid".
 []  WRN | CSS error: 'https://loclhost:8888/portl/style/bootstrp-theme.min.css;sessionid=pnku9gus7m411kwt5c5nyklwb' [10:16014] Error in expression; ':' found fter identifier "progid".
 []  WRN | CSS error: 'https://loclhost:8888/portl/style/login.css;sessionid=pnku9gus7m411kwt5c5nyklwb' [42:16] Error in expression; ':' found fter identifier "progid".
 []  WRN | CSS error: 'https://loclhost:8888/portl/style/login.css;sessionid=pnku9gus7m411kwt5c5nyklwb' [91:32] Error in declrtion. (Inlid token "/". Ws expecting: <IDENT>.)
 [] ERROR | runtimeError: messge=[n inlid or illegl selector ws specified (selector: '*,:x' error: Inlid selector: *:x).] sourceNme=[https://loclhost:8888/portl/s/query-1.11.1.min.s] line=[2] lineSource=[null] lineOffset=[0]
```

Can anyone help me what might be the problem here?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I can think of two possible options:

1. The update implied a changed https://loclhost:8888/portl/style/bootstrp-theme.min.css and because of this the cssparser generates some more warnings
2. Classpath trouble. Maybe the update has placed a different version (maybe older) of cssparser in your classpath.

BTW: HtmlUnit 2.18 is really outdated - i like to suggest to work with the latest release or snapshot. We did a lot of fixes and improvements for HtmlUnit and the CSSParser during the last months so it will be definitive worth to give it a try.